# Reading WKT data results in border deformations

Tags: data-formats, projection

I am not a geoscientist (I do computer graphics), however I am trying to render some geospatial data encoded as a WKT file.

I have a `POLYGON` with 2 coordinates per point, which seems to be representing latitude and longitude values (this is a guess on my end).

I use spherical coordinates to map these points onto euclidean (x,y,z) points for rendering.

The first problem I am having is, I am calculating latitude as an angle from the z axis (which matches the north pole) and latitude from the x axis (which seems to intersect with Greenwich meridian).

To my understanding this should guarantee correct positioning, alas what I get is a very misplaced Canada. Moreover, even when I manage to place the border on the correct region, it is clear the border outline is highly deformed with regard to the earth sphere.

[image]

This is the projection formula I am using to project the border:

```
Eigen::Vector3d SphericalCoordinatesToEuclidean(const Eigen::Vector2d& point)
{
    const double longitude = (point.y()) * 2.f * M_PI / 360.f;
    const double latitude = (point.x()) * 2.f * M_PI / 360.f;

    return {
        sin(latitude) * sin(longitude), sin(latitude) * cos(longitude), cos(latitude)};
}
```

The full data set is gigantic, this is just the section comprising the canadian border (every 2 values seem to be a point):

https://gist.github.com/Makogan/1aec1ea701ae3c8cb3653506bc9d8873

Comment: You confuse latitude and longitude in your formula, hence Canada is rotated by 90°.